# How to install Tween Engine in Libgdx (Eclipse project)

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, tween

I am a newbie in Libgdx. I just started up Libgdx but I got struck up with TWEEN ENGINE ..!! I need the image to fade in and out. So I have added jar file as per this link [Tween Engine](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine) but I am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: isWindows
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglNativesLoader.load(LwjglNativesLoader.java:44)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:73)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:61)
at com.myfirstgame.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:10)
```

I have added jar in libs folder under android project then I have also added as an external jar file under properties->Libraries but nothing worked out.I really don't know how to resolve it. Please help.Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Why not try using Android Studio?  I had a similar issue and I switched to Android Studio and the problem went away.

Comment: Do we need to add jar in the same way as above even in Android Studio?? @ Red Cricket

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-%28Eclipse%2C-Intellij-IDEA%2C-NetBeans%29

Comment: I have android studio and I have imported Libgdx files too I am asking about Tween jar @RedCricket

Comment: Looks at the doc https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine ... you want to follow the "FileTree Dependency Method (Easiest)"

Answer (score 4):

I resolved the error.I have downloaded jar from this link [TweenEngine](http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/downloads/list) extracted in a folder and added jar to my project.

I added jar by,
      Project->Properties->Libraries->and added both of the extracted files one by one.Then again,

Project->Properties->order and export->and click both of the jar files added 
click ok and Clean your project
Its done :)